# Проверка на возможность вычисления корня

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Необходимо проверить, можно ли вычислить корень из числа n. Если нет, то вызвать соответствующее сообщение.

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог: галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: Из любого числа больше нуля можно вычислить корень. И из числа меньше нуля тоже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант с выведением корня из любого неотрицательного числа:

```
import math

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Введите число: '))
        n = math.sqrt(n)
        print(n)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('ОШИБКА!!!!!!!!!!!! НЕЛЬЗЯ ВЫВЕСТИ КВАДРАТНЫЙ КОРЕНЬ ИЗ ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОГО ЧИСЛА!!!!!!! ПОВТОРИТЕ ВВОД!!!!')
        continue
```

---

Второй вариант с выведением только целого корня из неотрицательного числа:

```
import math

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Введите число: '))
        n = math.sqrt(n)
        if n % 1 == 0:
            print(n)
            break
        else:
            print('ОШИБКА!!!! ИЗ ЭТОГО ЧИСЛА НЕ ВЫВОДИТСЯ ЦЕЛЫЙ КОРЕНЬ!!! ПОВТОРИТЕ ВВОД!!!')
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('ОШИБКА!!!! НЕЛЬЗЯ ВЫВЕСТИ КВАДРАТНЫЙ КОРЕНЬ ИЗ ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОГО ЧИСЛА!!! ПОВТОРИТЕ ВВОД!!!')
        continue
```

Comment: Ну вот зачем вы поощряете использование сайта как решебника для людей, которые не хотят учиться?

Comment: @tutankhamun, потому что сам был в такой ситуации. В 6 классе только только начинал учить PascalABC(посоветовали начать с него, т.к. он изёвый) ну и дали задание, но не объяснили что и как делается(просто поставили перед фактом что надо это сделать и всё). Инфы нигде не было, пришлось спрашивать решение на маил ответах, а потом разбирать код по кусочкам и запоминать.

Comment: Только сейчас по языкам программирования не может быть ситуации "инфы нигде не было". Попыток решения со стороны спрашивающего никаких. Мне кажется, это говорит о том что человек не заинтересован научиться и я бы не стал такое поощрять. Собственно это объяснение "почему минус" под вашим ответом